# Issue with MySQL select where clause in left join

Tags: mysql

I've got an order items & a parts table, which i'm joining on the part ID foreign key:

```
SELECT orderID,qty,minorder 
FROM 
  orderitem 
LEFT JOIN 
  parts 
ON orderitem.partID=parts.partID 
WHERE orderitem.orderID='2128' AND qty < minorder
```

When i perform this query, i am getting no results. [When i remove the `qty < minorder` from the where clause, i get the following.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIGB2.png)

I'm' trying to craft this query so i get the 2nd record (where the qty is less than the minorder).

Any ideas?

Comment: Are your qty and minorder columns numeric or strings?  A String 15 would not be less than the string 1234...

Comment: That's exactly what it was thanks, this works:

    select orderID,qty,minorder from orderitem right join parts ON orderitem.partID=parts.partID where orderitem.orderID='2128' AND CAST(qty AS DECIMAL) < CAST(minorder AS DECIMAL)

Comment: Given the output, I would say the that qty and minorder are strings (left-justified).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my comment above, if your data types are strings, just add this to your query...

```
select orderID,qty,minorder from orderitem left join parts ON orderitem.partID=parts.partID where orderitem.orderID='2128' AND (0+qty) < (0+minorder)
```

By adding a numeric to a string, it will implicitly convert to number and perform the expected comparison.